# Exception: The data execution is not started because the data object is currently in error state. DataSource.updateSpec()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

Trying to assist an analyst with this error it's written in google app scripts. The job is scheduled every hour and it occasionally fails with. This executes a sql in bigquery and populates a google sheet.

Exception: The data execution is not started because the data object is currently in error state. Please check and update specification with DataSource.updateSpec().
    at RefreshDataSource(macros:9:57)

You can rerun it and it works perfectly. Not sure where to start debugging this, any assistance is appreciated. I can run the query in BQ anytime.

```
 /** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function RefreshDataSource() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('JIRA Security Review'), true);
  SpreadsheetApp.enableAllDataSourcesExecution();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getDataSourceTables()[0].refreshData();
};
```

Answer (score 4):

This does not answer why it is happening, but as for a way to deal with it, you can try using `forceRefreshData()` in place of `refreshData()`.

`forceRefreshData()` will refresh your data regardless of the error state (it refreshes data regardless of the current state).

Here's a link to documentation:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-source-table#forceRefreshData()

Hope this is helpful!